# Star Ratings Javascript is not working properly in Index Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rating-system

**I've implemented a Star Rating System using this tutorial** http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3

Everything works in the **SHOW PAGE**, But in the **INDEX PAGE**, the JavaScript does not work. When the page is loaded, Every Book in the index page has the same rating as the first Book and it doesn't load the correct Star Rating to each book on the page.

**(Am I missing something in the beginning of my JavaScript code, like an ID?)**

New to rails please help :)

**JAVASCRIPT**

rating_ballot.js

```
### Sets up the stars to match the data when the page is loaded. 
### But applies the first Books Rating to all

$(function () {
  var checkedId = $('form.rating_ballot > input:checked').attr('id');
  $('form.rating_ballot > label[for=' + checkedId + ']').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('bright');
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    ### Makes stars glow on hover.
  $('form.rating_ballot > label').hover(
    function() {    // mouseover
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('glow');
    },function() {  // mouseout
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().removeClass('glow');
  });

  ### Makes stars stay glowing after click.
  $('form.rating_ballot > label').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("bright");
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass("bright");
  });

  ### Submits the form & saves data.
  $(document).on('change', '.rating_button', function(){
    $(this).parent().submit();
  });
});
```

**CSS.SCSS**

```
form.rating_ballot input.rating_button { display: none; }

form.rating_ballot label.rating { cursor: pointer; display: block; height: 20px; width: 20px; float: left; }
form.rating_ballot label.rating span { display: none; }
form.rating_ballot label.rating { background-image:  image-url('star-dim.png'); }
form.rating_ballot label.rating.bright { background-image:  image-url('star-bright.png'); }
form.rating_ballot label.rating.glow { background-image:  image-url('star-glow.png'); }
```

**VIEWS**

show.html.erb (show)

```
<div id="book<%= @book.id %>">
 <div id="rating">
   <%= render :partial => 'ratings/rating', :locals =>{:book => @book} %>
 </div>
</div>
```

index.hrml.erb (books)

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <table id="book<%= book.id %>">
    <tbody>  
      <tr>  
        <td>
          <%= book.title %>
        </td> 
      </tr> 

      <tr>

        <td  id="rating">                   
          <%= render :partial => 'ratings/rating', :locals =>{:book => book} %>
        </td>

      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

_rating.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(rating_ballot(issue.id), :html => { :class => 'rating_ballot' }, remote: true ) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label("value_1", content_tag(:span, '1'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"1"}) %>
  <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 1, current_user_rating(issue.id) == 1, :class => 'rating_button') %>

  <%= f.label("value_2", content_tag(:span, '2'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"2"}) %>
  <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 2, current_user_rating(issue.id) == 2, :class => 'rating_button') %>

  <%= f.label("value_3", content_tag(:span, '3'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"3"}) %>
  <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 3, current_user_rating(issue.id) == 3, :class => 'rating_button') %>

  <%= f.label("value_4", content_tag(:span, '4'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"4"}) %>
  <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 4, current_user_rating(issue.id) == 4, :class => 'rating_button') %>

  <%= f.label("value_5", content_tag(:span, '5'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"5"}) %>
  <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 5, current_user_rating(issue.id) == 5, :class => 'rating_button') %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag("issue_id", issue.id) %>
  <%= f.submit :Submit, style: "display: none" %>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb & update.js.erb

```
$('#issue<%= @issue.id%> #rating').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'ratings/rating', :locals => {:issue => @issue}) %>");
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :current_user, only: [:create, :update]

  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:book_id])
    @rating = Rating.create(params[:rating])    
    @rating.book_id = @book.id
    @rating.user_id = current_user.id
    if @rating.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:book_id])
    @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_book_id(@book_id)
    if @rating.update_attributes(params[:rating])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**HELPERS**

```
module IssuesHelper

  def rating_ballot(issue_id)
    if @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_issue_id(issue_id)
        @rating
    else
        current_user.ratings.new
    end
  end

  def current_user_rating(issue_id)
    if @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_issue_id(issue_id)
       @rating.value
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two totally different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
$(function () {
  var checkedId = $('form.rating_ballot > input:checked').attr('id');
  $('form.rating_ballot > label[for=' + checkedId + ']').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('bright');
});
```

It gets the `id` of the first checked input, and for all forms sets the star rating to that one.

Try this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('form.rating_ballot').each(function() {
        var $form = $(this),
              checkedInput = $form.find('input:checked');

        checkedInput.prevAll().andSelf().addClass('bright');
    });
});
```

Comment: Btw, could that also be the reason why I am experiencing the same problem when someone Clicks on a Star Rating. Currently, it only seems to update the first Book. I have posted the question to this here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847977/star-rating-system-is-only-updating-first-item-on-the-list

Comment: can you help me out please, I'm not too familiar with javascript.